# Shopify API - Payments

Tags: shopify

I have been reviewing the API documentation for Shopify and am trying to figure out if the cost of an item selected from the 'Store' can be passed in a Get command back to a different website so a different website can charge for the Item along with other charges from a website ...and then once the payment goes through on the website, send a POST to shopify that the sale was complete and proceed with fulfilling the order?

Our software is newspaper software so we provide newspapers with subscriber web portals were customers can sign up and pay for a newspaper subscription.

We would like to offer the ability to add Single Sales items to what a customer purchases and we want to be able to do it in one payment transaction

I have reviewed the various Shopify API documentation but it is not clear if the API supports getting cost info and posting a successful charge back to Shopify to complete the fulfillment step. We are looking to be able to GET the cost for a selected single sale item passed to us from the Shopify API so that we can add it to the Amount we pass to the Payment Gateway we integrate with and when the payment goes through, send Shopify a success on the payment.

The ultimate goal is to have a customer make one payment that can include single sales items as well as a newspaper subscription or day pass.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a POST and [create an Order](https://docs.shopify.com/api/order#create) using the Shopify API once (at your side) are sure the payment has gone through.